# Вывод meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress, запрос

Возникла проблема:

```
 $massive = 'D';
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'key',
                'value' => $massive,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
```

'compare' => 'LIKE' - указанная в value подстрока имеется в строке $massive. Выводятся записи где присутствует значение 'D'. Например `D, DOM, MANSARD, STUDENT`. Как сделать чтобы выводилось только `'D'`, а не все значения где есть буква D?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте '=':

```
$massive = 'D';
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'key',
            'value' => $massive,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
```

Comment: `'compare' => '=',` - не подходит т.к. тогда должно быть точное вхождение `'D'`, а у меня бывают вот такие значения в массиве: `D, D CLASS, D MANSARD`. Нужно что бы `'compare'` отбирал по первому слову :/

Comment: Про первое слово в вопросе - ни слова. Поэтому какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Comment: Выбрать запись по первому слову средствами MySQL невозможно